# Is it possible to apply [Rule Chain] after [Data Converter]?

Tags: thingsboard

I am currently working on a POC by using ThingsBoard PE.
Our raw data contains [Asset] [Attributes].

Data flow: 
`[IoT cloud] --https webhook carry raw data--> [ThingsBoard PE HTTP INTEGRATION] --uplink--> [ThingsBoard PE Data Converter]`

My question is: is it possible to apply [Rule Chain] after [ThingsBoard PE Data Converter]? Therefore, the device can auto create relationship with [Asset] by the [Attribute], instead of [AssetName].

Example data after data converter process:

```
{
    "deviceName": "ABC",
    "deviceType": "temperature",
    "attributes": {
        "asset_id": 6 // <-- the id is used in asset attribute
    },
    "telemetry": {
        "temperature": 39.43
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your two, separate questions:

> is it possible to apply [Rule Chain] after [ThingsBoard PE Data Converter]?

Yes it is possible. Once your data is successfully integrated and you are receiving it, you can access it using the `[Input]` Rule Node (the default green one that is always there when you create a Rule) and route it to any other node you need.

> Therefore, the device can auto create relationship with [Asset] by the [Attribute], instead of [AssetName].

So, you want the relationship to take your custom attribute and use *that* as the pattern that identifies the Asset you want to create the relationship from.

The PE edition already has the [Create Relation Node](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/action-nodes/#create-relation-node). However, seems that as it is one is not able to do what you seek (has no option to specify custom Asset id).

However, two options you got are:

- **Create a Custom Rule Node** that does what you want. For that try checking the [Rule Node Development](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/rule-node-development/) page from Thingsboard. You can use the Create Relation Node as base and work from there. This can be a longer solution than doing...
- **Enrich your incoming message's metadata, adding your desired attribute**. The Create Relation Node allows you to use variables on your message's metadata in your Name and Type patterns, as seen from this screenshot I took from that node:

[image: Node Screenshot]

This allows us a workaround to what you want to do: *Add a [Script Transformation Node](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/transformation-nodes/#script-transformation-node) that adds `attributes.asset_id` to the metadata*, for example as `metadata.asset_id`, so you can then use it as `${asset_id}` on your Name and Type patterns.

For example, your `Transform()` method of such Script Transformation Node should look something like this:

```
function Transform(msg, metadata, msgType){
    //assumming your desired id is msg.attributes.asset_id, add it to the metadata
    metadata.asset_id = msg.attributes.asset_id;
    //return the message, in your case to the Create Relation Node
    return {msg: msg, metadata:metadata, msgType:msgType};
}
```

Finally, your Rule should be connected like this:

> [Input] -> [Script Node] -> [Create Relation Node] -> [...whatever else you like]